# Refresh database and delete entry

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I made a database that consists of field `[id, name, lastname, time]` Is there a function that would refresh database after 22h and delete all data deleted from the database.

It is a web application for reserving tables at a club. and the reservation lasts up to 22 hours, after that, it is cleared and the table becomes free.

Comment: `cron jobs` will do that for you

Comment: In addition to @Gautam3164: But you have to write your own method to do it. The cronjob will help you calling it every 24 hours.

Answer (score 3):

You need a cron job that runs every 5 minutes. Just search the net on how to run a php cron jobs.

You need a php script which will have a delete query which identify the database rows which has time > 22 hours.

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE time > NOW() - INTERVAL 22 HOURS
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Gautam3164 and @TobiasKun. You can write your code like this and run it in cron.

```
 <?php
    $DBHOST = 'localhost';
    $DB = 'testdb';
    $User = 'testuser';
    $Pass = 'testpass';
    $Table = 'testtb2';
    mysql_connect($DBHOST,$User,$Pass);
    mysql_select_db($DB);
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM $Table WHERE time_created < now() - interval 22 hours");

    ?>
```

Comment: You might want to delete records with a specific range i.e. 22 hours instead of deleting everything.